# Running Hadoop on Windows getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: .createDirectoryWithMode0

Tags: windows, hadoop

Trying to run Hadoop on windows and getting this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode(NativeIO.java:521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:555)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1338)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1359)
    at dat.MaxTemperatureDriver.run(MaxTemperatureDriver.java:30)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
    at dat.MaxTemperatureDriver.main(MaxTemperatureDriver.java:37)

I already have winutils.exe, hadoop.dll, vcredist_x64.dll, vc_redist.x64.exe, vcredist_arm.exe, hdfs.dll in hadoop home/bin directory. and have that directory in PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. What am I still missing?

Comment: Have you built your own binaries of Hadoop?

Comment: I copied everything from the web. Hadoop 2.8.0, untar the files, and what is needed, I just go to the web to find it and download it, and add them to the bin directory or to the external jar in eclipse.